# Get file's size from bytes array (without saving to disc)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a byte's array and I want to calculate what would be the file size if I'll write these bytes to file. Is it possible without writing the file to disc?

Comment: `Byte[] arr;` `int size = arr.Length;`

Comment: Byte are size itself :) KB, MB just count how many there are

Answer (score 119, accepted):

What about `array.Length`? Looks like a size in bytes.

Comment: Wouldn't it return the total no of elements in array?

Comment: As Jon Skeet mentions in his answer, a byte of memory is a byte on disk. This means that `yes` this will give you the number of elements in the byte array, but it also means, that the byte array length is the number of bytes

Answer (score 64):

Um, yes:

```
int length = byteArray.Length;
```

A byte in memory would be a byte on disk... at least in higher level file system terms. You also need to potentially consider how many individual blocks/clusters would be used (and overhead for a directory entry), and any compression that the operating system may supply, but it's not clear from the question whether that's what you're after.

If you really *do* want to know the "size on disk" as opposed to the file size (in the same way that Windows can show the two numbers) I suspect you'd genuinely have to write it to disk - and then use a Win32 API to find out the actual size on disk.

Answer (score 8):

`Array.Length` would give your total size expressed in byte.

Physical dimension on disk may be a little bit more considering cluster size.

Answer (score 7):

some time ago I found this snipped and since then I like to do this

```
public static string GetSizeInMemory(this long bytesize)
{


    string[] sizes = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    double len = Convert.ToDouble(bytesize);
    int order = 0;
    while(len >= 1024D && order < sizes.Length - 1)
    {
        order++;
        len /= 1024;
    }

    return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0:0.##} {1}", len, sizes[order]);
}
```

You can use this extension method when accessing anything that provides file or memory size like a FileInfo or a Process, bellow are 2 samples

```
private void ValidateResources(object _)
{

        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        double now = p.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        double cpuUsage = (now - processorTime) / MONITOR_INTERVAL;
        processorTime = now;

        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out int maxThreads, out int _);
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out int availThreads, out int _);

        int cpuQueue = maxThreads - availThreads;
        var displayString= string.Concat(
                  p.WorkingSet64.GetSizeInMemory() + "/"
                , p.PeakWorkingSet64.GetSizeInMemory(), " RAM, "
                , p.Threads.Count, " threads, ", p.HandleCount.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                , " handles,  ", Math.Min(cpuUsage, 1).ToString("P2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                , " CPU usage, ", cpuQueue, " CPU queue depth"

            ));

}
```

or with a file

```
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathtoFile);
    string displaySize= file.Length.GetSizeInMemory();
```

Comment: I feel like this helps determine unit-of-measure for a certain byte size, but doesn't really answer the question; which is, how do you determine the value sent into this function? (i.e., where did "bytesize" get its value?)

Comment: @TSmith, sure, good point, I added two samples using a file and using a Process, anything that shows size in bytes will work